# How can I filter out rows from linear regression based on another linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I would like to conduct a linear regression that will have three steps: **1)** Running the regression on all data points **2)** Taking out the 10 outiers as found by using the absolute distanse value of `rstandard` **3)** Running the regression again on the new data frame.
I know how to do it manually but these is very awkwarding. Is there a way to do it automatically? Can it be done for taking out columns as well?

Here is my toy data frame and code (I'll take out 2 top outliers):

```
df <- read.table(text = "userid target birds    wolfs     
                 222       1        9         7 
                 444       1        8         4 
                 234       0        2         8 
                 543       1        2         3 
                 678       1        8         3 
                 987       0        1         2 
                 294       1        7         16 
                 608       0        1         5 
                 123       1        17        7 
                 321       1        8         7 
                 226       0        2         7 
                 556       0        20        3 
                 334       1        6         3 
                 225       0        1         1 
                 999       0        3         11 
                 987       0        30         1  ",header = TRUE) 
model<- lm(target~ birds+ wolfs,data=df)
rstandard <- abs(rstandard(model))
df<-cbind(df,rstandard)
g<-subset(df,rstandard > sort(unique(rstandard),decreasing=T)[3])
g
       userid target birds wolfs rstandard    
    4     543      1     2     3  1.189858    
   13    334      1     6     3  1.122579  

   modelNew<- lm(target~ birds+ wolfs,data=df[-c(4,13),])
```

Comment: Can you explain your rule for determining what qualifies as an outlier? According to your code, it's the cases with the two highest values from `abs(rstandard())`, but that seems pretty arbitrary. I ask because it would be easier to do this with a rule that was about value instead of relative rank.

Comment: Hello  @ulfelder, the rule is based on many tests that I did upon a big dataset that I have.Actually I intended to test this rule on other data sets that I have, that the reason that I would like to automate it .

Comment: So just to clarify, the rule you want to apply consistently is: throw out the two most influential cases?

Comment: Yes @ulfelder.But the important thing is to find out if there is a way to remove rows or columns based on a filter as part of the regression.The filter can be changed for example mybe Bonferonni test will be better but how can I filter the results inside the regression itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you could do this without estimating two models, the first to identify the most influential cases and the second on the data without those cases. You could simplify your code and avoid cluttering the workspace, however, by doing it all in one shot, with the subsetting process embedded in the call to estimate the "final" model. Here's code that does this for the example you gave:

```
model <- lm(target ~ birds + wolfs,
    data = df[-(as.numeric(names(sort(abs(rstandard(lm(target ~ birds + wolfs, data=df))), decreasing=TRUE)))[1:2]),])
```

Here, the initial model, evaluation of influence, and ensuing subsetting of the data are all built into the code that comes after the first `data =`.

Also, note that the resulting model will differ from the one your code produced. That's because your `g` did not correctly identify the two most influential cases, as you can see if you just eyeball the results of `abs(rstandard(lm(target ~ birds + wolfs, data=df)))`. I think it has to do with your use of `unique()`, which seems unnecessary, but I'm not sure.